# Yii2: How to merge to relations as one

Tags: merge, yii2, relation

I have two relations

```
public function getAnnounceComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AnnounceComment::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}


public function getAnnounceRates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AnnounceRate::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

How can I merge User's two relations as one on same `announce_id` then I can call this like
`$user->commentAndRate->comment` or `$user->commentAndRate->rate`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It will only make accessing these relations less convenient.

Comment: because İ want to use in a foreach loop like this. foreach($user->commentsAndRates as $com) echo $com->comment . $com->rate;

Comment: But how you can be sure that specific comment is related to specific rate? I guess you don't want to display random comment with random rate.

Comment: According to announce_id. I had a solution. Thanks for your help. Adding to answers

Answer (score 0):

I did like that:

Added this relation to `AnnounceComment` model:

```
public function getRate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AnnounceRate::className(), ['announce_id' => 'announce_id']);
}
```

And when I call User did like this:

```
$user = User::find()->with('announceComments.rate')->where('id=1')->one()
```

Then I can easily call :

```
foreach ($model->announceComments as $key => $comment) {
    echo $comment->text . $comment->rate->count`
}
```

I wait for better answers :)